# Fancybox reload select box on close

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, fancybox, modal-dialog

I would like to know if it's possible to refresh/reload only a select box in a rails form after closing a iframe modal Fancybox.

I could reload the whole page using:

```
'onClosed': function() {parent.location.reload(true);},
```

But the problem is that it "reloads" the whole form losing the fields populated by the user before launching the modal Fancybox...

How can I only refresh the select box (I'm using Jquery)?